# Installing Ubuntu onto externally mounted internal hard-drive

Tags: system-installation

Ok, ubuntu noob here!!!

I have a netbook, which I'd like to run Ubuntu on, this will soon have a new HDD in.
Can I connect this to a desktop PC in such a way that I can install Ubuntu onto the new HDD, then put it back into the netbook, and it will work on the netbook?

Many thanks,

(hopefully not a duplicate)

Comment: yes, you can. Do you have necessary cables to connect the HDD directly to the desktop PC?

Comment: @Ron probably not... I guess Amazon is my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, yes it will work and this is the secret power of Linux, since most drivers will be bundeled within the Kernel itself, then you'll not face much problems when moving some bootable storage device to another PC.

But you **may** face some problem mainly in two parts, the Video Card and the Wireless, so you have to install their drivers yourself such as
NVIDIA cards.

Comment: Ah, ok. It has an Ethernet adapter, which I suppose helps in the case that WLAN connection needs drivers.

Comment: Yes you can do that easily